Unit Testing in Ceedling using ASSERT Statements
I am writing test cases in Ceedling for the below function with assert statement :
 fsp_err_t ad7606c_init(const bsp_io_port_pin_t cs, const spi_instance_t* spi)
   {
fsp_err_t result = FSP_SUCCESS;
    uint8_t rx[20] = {0};

    /* write config reg use 1 d out line */
       volatile ad7606c_config_reg_t config = {.DOUT_FORMAT = 0};
       write_reg(cs, spi, AD7606C_REG_CONFIG, config.REG);
    /* read config reg */
       read_reg(cs, spi, AD7606C_REG_CONFIG, 1, rx);

    /* read id reg */
       read_reg(cs, spi, AD7606C_REG_ID, 1, rx);
    /* id must be 0x32 */
       assert(rx[1] == ID);

    /* write range reg */
       volatile ad7606c_range_reg_t range = {.CH1_RANGE =          AD7606C_RANGE_12500M_TO_12500P_DIFF, .CH2_RANGE = AD7606C_RANGE_12500M_TO_12500P_DIFF};
       write_reg(cs, spi, AD7606C_REG_RANGE_CH1_CH2, range.REG);
       write_reg(cs, spi, AD7606C_REG_RANGE_CH3_CH4, range.REG);
       write_reg(cs, spi, AD7606C_REG_RANGE_CH5_CH6, range.REG);
       write_reg(cs, spi, AD7606C_REG_RANGE_CH7_CH8, range.REG);

       #ifdef INTERFACE_CHECK 
         write_reg(cs, spi, AD7606C_REG_DIGITAL_DIAG_ENA, 0x81);
       #endif

       return result;
     }

I followed the steps mentioned in
https://www.electronvector.com/blog/unit-testing-with-asserts
Still getting the below error:
ERROR: Test executable "test_ad7606c.out" failed.

Produced no final test result counts in $stdout:
Assertion failed: rx[1] == ID, file src/ad7606c/ad7606c.c, line 59

62:test_ad7606c_init_normal_initialization:PASS

And exited with status: [0] (count of failed tests).
This is often a symptom of a bad memory access in source or test code.

I have created a helper file as below:
    #ifndef ASSERT_UNIT_TEST_SUPPORT_H_
    #define ASSERT_UNIT_TEST_SUPPORT_H_

    #include "CException.h"

    #define TEST_ASSERT_FAIL_ASSERT(_code_under_test)         \
    {                                                         \
      CEXCEPTION_T e;                                         \
      Try {                                                   \
        _code_under_test;                                     \                                    
        TEST_FAIL_MESSAGE("Code under test did not assert");  \  
      } Catch(e) {}                                           \
    }

    #define TEST_ASSERT_PASS_ASSERT(_code_under_test)               \
     {                                                              \
      CEXCEPTION_T e;                                               \
      Try {                                                         \
        _code_under_test;                                           \
       } Catch(e) {                                                 \
        TEST_FAIL_MESSAGE("Code under test failed an assertion");   \
     }                                                              \
    }

   #endif

The test file is as below:
     #include "unity.h"
     #include "r_spi_api.h"   
     #include "bsp_io.h"
     #include "ad7606c.h"
     #include "Helper.h"
     #include "mock_regread.h"


     // Definitions for testing
        #define CS_PIN 1                    // Chip select pin mock value
        #define SPI_INSTANCE NULL           // SPI instance mock (assuming a null pointer for simplicity)

        void test_ad7606c_init_id_mismatch(void)
             {
              uint8_t rx[20] = {0};
              rx[1] = 0x00; // Incorrect ID value

             // Expected sequence
              write_reg_Expect(CS_PIN, SPI_INSTANCE, AD7606C_REG_CONFIG, 0);
              read_reg_Expect(CS_PIN, SPI_INSTANCE, AD7606C_REG_CONFIG, 1, rx);
              read_reg_Expect(CS_PIN, SPI_INSTANCE, AD7606C_REG_ID, 1, rx);

              //ad7606c_init(CS_PIN, SPI_INSTANCE);

              // Call the function and expect assertion failure
              TEST_ASSERT_FAIL_ASSERT(ad7606c_init(CS_PIN, SPI_INSTANCE));
              }


Ceedling's "Unity" is not related to the Unity game engine.  Tags edited.


Still getting the below error

I guess the implied question is why you are getting that error, and what to do about it.  As to why ...

I followed the steps mentioned in https://www.electronvector.com/blog/unit-testing-with-asserts

No, it does not appear that you did.  The behavior, including messaging, produced by your code shows that you are using C's standard assert() macro, whereas the blog post describes writing your own, differently spelled and differently-behaved assertion macro.
When a standard C assertion fails, it aborts the program.  This is what you observe.  It is consistent with the intended usage of such assertions to document and, optionally, programmatically check invariants assumed by the program.  You should be able to prove that your C assert()s will not fail, so if such an assertion ever does fail then it means that the program is wrong.  Either the assertion itself is wrong, or an invariant on which the program depends is not satisfied (so the program either must not assume it or must be corrected so that it is actually invariant), or the assert() feature has been used incorrectly.
The blog post suggests writing and using an alternative assertion macro or function that is targeted differently, at checking incorrect or unexpected -- but conceivable -- runtime conditions.  It proposes that such a macro would provide a means to configure a different kind of failure response in a testing scenario than it does in real-world operation.  That's perfectly reasonable, but it's a different sense of "assertion".  You don't appear to have written or used such a macro.

I have created a helper file as below:

Ok, but that's not suitable for use in testing C assert()ions. And again, if those are used properly, then it shouldn't be possible to provoke them to fail, so they are not amenable to that kind of testing in the first place.
As for what to do about it:

use C assert()ions correctly.
if you want runtime checks of conditions that might not, in fact, be satisfied, then implement those using something other than assert().  Your blog post defines and uses a macro named ASSERT() for this purpose, but there is nothing special about that particular name.  I would be inclined to choose something different, myself, exactly to avoid confusion with standard assert().
if you want to test failure of those runtime validation / consistency checks then, as the blog suggests, provide a way to select between failure behavior appropriate for testing and failure behavior appropriate for real operation.

